# Session issue in Weblogic Appserver

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

We have a Web app is deployed on weblogic and when we log in it gets logged in but subsequent any click/call is again showing log in screen. Not sure why this happening did not find any related logs.

After several restart of managed server it works for few hours and again we encounter same problem again we need several restart to get it working state.

I have verified application logs, nodemanager logs, access logs and did not any specific error message.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you deploy your application to several managed servers ? It sounds like a session cookie issue and/or a load balancing issue.

Comment: We are hitting the application directly, not through loadbalancer. what you mean session cookie issue, any particular steps to verify. I have verified the cookie and it contains JSESSIONID also.

Comment: does your jsessionid cookie value changes for each request ?

Comment: Next request it self again throws the user to login page.

Comment: does your jsessionid cookie value changes for each request ?